# cant generate Relations table useing strapi cli

Tags: api, strapi

I nede generate Relations Models useing strapi cli 
I looked through the documents, and there was nothing.
All the talking about the admin GUI

Answer (score 0):

This feature doesn't exist in strapi.

It's not planned in the [Public Roadmap](https://portal.productboard.com/strapi) for now.

If you want this feature available, I suggest you contribute to strapi to add it by submitting a pull request.

But this feature needs a [strapi/rfcs](http://github.com/strapi/rfcs) before starting to work on it. We will have to propose a syntax to create a relation via the CLI args.